# Fork/Join Parallel Patterns

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, fork-join

Always been a tad weak around with threads and just going through [Steven Toub's Parallel Computing](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19222) book.

On Page 39 there are examples of Fork/Join patterns below

```
static T[] MyParallelInvoke<T>(params Func<T>[] functions)
{
  T[] results = new T[functions.Length];
  Parallel.For(0, functions.Length, i =>
  {
     results[i] = functions[i]();
  });
  return results;
}
```

---

```
// Approach #4: Using PLINQ
static T[] MyParallelInvoke<T>(params Func<T>[] functions)
{
  return functions.AsParallel().Select(f => f()).ToArray();
}
```

For Approach 3 for example above just to clarify do the results all offically have values,
when you do

"return results"?

Or will only some of them have values depending on if the Thread has been completed or not?

Similarly for Approach 4 when you call `ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in both case there is an implicit `WaitAll()`.

The code outside `Parallel.For()` is single-threaded.

Comment: How do you know when this implicit WaitAll is called. Is it anytime like I try to access the results array outside the Parallel loop that I will know WaitAll is called?

Comment: The `Parallel.For();` is one statement. When you're 'after' this statement all threads inside it are done.

Comment: Seeing that there are a few approaches, how would you determine which is the best approach? Thanks

Comment: @AllenHo The option depends mostly on circumstance, like how to get/store/use the results. The threading is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel.For() will return a ParallelLoopResult that has an IsCompleted property.

Comment: I can't Imagine when this would be 'false'. After an exception perhaps.

Comment: If Stop or Break is called you might not have all the results you expect. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx

Comment: Right. But it is not (can not be) signaling that Threads are still underway.